# How can I trigger an action, when a template is loaded in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

each time, a template is shown, i'd like to do something -- for example an alert.

Here is a minimalistic example of these templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    index template. {{#link-to "other"}} go to other Template {{/link-to}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="other">
    other template {{#link-to "index"}} go to index {{/link-to}}
</script>
```

I tried the following, but none of these 2 versions worked.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('other');
});


App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        loading: function(){ alert("index called"); }
    }
});

App.OtherRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        loading: function(){ alert("Other called") }
    }
});
```

So, what's the right right way to trigger an action, when the template is shown? To put the action in the link-to helper is no option, because the action should also be triggered, if the user opens "/other" without clicking a link (opening the url ...#/other).

Comment: Check the loading event in your route. The ember guide explains a similar case http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/.

Comment: Do u want to trigger the action when a template is rendered, *or* when the route is changing? Maybe override `Em.Route#setupController` directly? Also look for `didInserElement` on the View!

Comment: When the route is changing. setupController seems to be the right way. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Ember.js site about [Routing](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) it states:

> You can customize the behavior of a route by creating an Ember.Route subclass.

In your case:

```
App.OtherRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   setupController: function(){
       alert("foobar");
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe this answer is helpful. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374694/how-can-i-trigger-an-action-to-draw-on-a-canvas-immediately-after-the-template-l)