# How can I trigger an action to draw on a canvas immediately after the template loaded?

Tags: templates, events, canvas, ember.js

I want to draw on a canvas in a template immediately after the template loaded, so I think I need a suitable hook (event) to do it but I could not find one.

I read the answer for [How can I trigger an action, when a template is loaded in ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056818/how-can-i-trigger-an-action-when-a-template-is-loaded-in-ember) and I tried to use "setupController" event to do it but it did not work.

**template.hbs**

```
<canvas id="lyric-editor" width="200" height="200"/>
```

**route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('lyric-editor');
    console.log(canvas:" + canvas); 
    // the result is null, it means the template is not loaded at this time.
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; // Color of the bars
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 40, 40);
  }
```

There are beforeModel method and afterModel method in the Ember.route class so I expected something like **afterTempalteLoad** method.

Any hints are appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a component (by using `ember g component canvas-component in the terminal`) and in the component use the didInsertElement hook.

So in canvas-component (or whatever you choose to call it)

```
didInsertElement() {
   this._super(...arguments);

   const canvas = this.$();
   console.log(canvas:" + canvas); 
}
```

I definitely recommend reading through the [ember docs about components](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/)

Comment: Thank your quick answer, Iguchi. It works perfectly and the link is very useful, I'll read it through.